# Getting metadata from an audio stream

Tags: ios, ios4, metadata, audio-streaming, avqueueplayer

I would like to get the file name and, if possible, album image from a streaming URL in a AVPlayerItem that I am playing with AVQueuePlayer but I don't know how to go about doing this.

Also if it turns out that my streaming URL doesn't have any metadata can I put metadata in my `NSURL*` before passing it to the AVPlayerItem?

Thanks.

Comment: I use the Dropbox API to get the stream URL

Comment: audio yes. but I think it doesn't matter if it is audio or video. They are both handled by the same AVPlayerItem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535465/how-to-fetch-resolution-supported-by-video-m38u-file-url-in-swift Help me Thank you in advanced....

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Well I am surprised no one has answered this question. 
In fact no one has answered any of my other questions.
Makes me wonder how much knowledge people in here truly have.

Anyways, I will go ahead and answer my own question.
I found out how to get the metadata by doing the following:

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
NSArray *metadataList = [playerItem.asset commonMetadata];
for (AVMetadataItem *metaItem in metadataList) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[metaItem commonKey]);
}
```

Which gives me a list as follows:

```
title
creationDate
artwork
albumName
artist
```

With that list now I know how to access the metadata from my audio stream. Just simply go through the `NSArray` and look for an `AVMetadataItem` that has the `commonKey` that I want (for example, `title`). Then when I find the `AVMetadataItem` just get the `value` property from it.

Now, this works great but it may be possible that when you try to get the data it will take a while. You can load the data asynchronously by sending `loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler:` to the `AVMetadataItem` you just found.

Hope that helps to anyone who may find themselves with the same problem.

Comment: for some reason my commond metadata is 0 value. Whereas timedmetadata has one value ["title"]

Comment: Good work on doing your own research and finding an answer. Kudos :)

Answer (score 2):

When retrieving a particular item I would use the Metadata common keys constant declared in AVMetadataFormat.h, i.e.: **AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle**.

```
NSUInteger titleIndex = [avItem.asset.commonMetadata indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    AVMutableMetadataItem *metaItem = (AVMutableMetadataItem *)obj;
    if ([metaItem.commonKey isEqualToString:AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}];

AVMutableMetadataItem *item = [avItem.asset.commonMetadata objectAtIndex:titleIndex];
NSString *title = (NSString *)item.value;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535465/how-to-fetch-resolution-supported-by-video-m38u-file-url-in-swift Help me Thank you in advanced....