# how to fetch resolution supported by video .m38u file url in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, m3u8, avkit

I am currently working on HTTP Live streaming video with AVPlayerViewController / AVPlayer

I am playing a video with .m3u8 file supported

It is playing fine but my question is that can I have the data of video like I have to set 4 types of resolution while generating the .m3u8 file.. , I can varies the resolution at my end point now the question is how to get the all values which i have setup at my endpoint. I am play this is in android also and using Track i am able to fetch all the video information but in ios how can i fetch all the details containing the video like its height , with, track,resolution supported by video etc..

I have search a lot but could not get succeed.. Need help Thanks in advance

```
    #EXTM3U

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="stereo",LANGUAGE="en",NAME="English",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="audio/stereo/en/128kbit.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="stereo",LANGUAGE="dubbing",NAME="Dubbing",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="audio/stereo/none/128kbit.m3u8"

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="surround",LANGUAGE="en",NAME="English",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="audio/surround/en/320kbit.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="surround",LANGUAGE="dubbing",NAME="Dubbing",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="audio/stereo/none/128kbit.m3u8"

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="Deutsch",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="de",URI="subtitles_de.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="English",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="en",URI="subtitles_en.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="Espanol",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="es",URI="subtitles_es.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="Français",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="fr",URI="subtitles_fr.m3u8"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=258157,CODECS="avc1.4d400d,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="stereo",RESOLUTION=422x180,SUBTITLES="subs"
video/250kbit.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=520929,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="stereo",RESOLUTION=638x272,SUBTITLES="subs"
video/500kbit.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=831270,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="stereo",RESOLUTION=638x272,SUBTITLES="subs"
video/800kbit.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1144430,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="surround",RESOLUTION=958x408,SUBTITLES="subs"
video/1100kbit.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1558322,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="surround",RESOLUTION=1277x554,SUBTITLES="subs"
video/1500kbit.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=4149264,CODECS="avc1.4d4028,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="surround",RESOLUTION=1921x818,SUBTITLES="subs"
video/4000kbit.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=6214307,CODECS="avc1.4d4028,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="surround",RESOLUTION=1921x818,SUBTITLES="subs"
video/6000kbit.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=10285391,CODECS="avc1.4d4033,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="surround",RESOLUTION=4096x1744,SUBTITLES="subs"
video/10000kbit.m3u8
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Did you got any solution? Will it be possible to get different quality options from .m3u8 file in IOS?

Comment: no @CoderSulemani

Comment: no @Uma Sankar Buddi

Comment: After some research I came to a conclusion that In iOS , We can fetch audio, subtitles tracks from a .m3u8 video but not different quality options. Even if you know Quality Options, we can't able to select those options using AVPlayerItem. :(

Comment: Hey @DivyeshGondaliya did you find the solution to extract the list of supportive resolution from the given m3u8 file?

Answer (score 0):

```
var urlData: Data!
var savedString: String!

urlString = "https://xcxc.xxxxx.app/mobile/test.m3u8"

if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                 urlData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                 savedString = String(data: urlData, encoding: .utf8)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, You can get the natural size of the video, if it is playing in the player. 
As you said that you're playing the URL in AVPlayer then use the following code to get the natural size of the playing track.

```
if let track = self.tampPlayer?.currentItem?.tracks.first {
        print("Size = \(track.assetTrack.naturalSize)")
}
```

No matter whatever the url is, if it's playing in player there will be the size for video defiantly.

Comment: i am talking about the resolution size....how can i get that....i have to create like quality list and change based on selected resolution like you tube.....have you any solution for that ?????

Comment: i tray your code but its return me 

~ DemoVideo.MediaPlaylist

Comment: To change the video quality, you've to create different urls for each bitrate like 144, 320, 480, 640, 720, 1080 etc. 
And have it on the player screen, whenever the user will change the bitrate you've to reload the player item with the url related to selected bitrate.

Comment: to change quality i have to set some list like 320,480,720 how to get this from url that is my point dear.....have some idea ???

Comment: whoever is creating the urls for different bitrates your backend partner or any third party. They will provide you the different urls to their respective bitrates.